# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el día del último lunes del mes en Android?

Tags: java, android

Necesito alguna forma de obtener el día en el que cae el último lunes de un determinado mes. No sé cómo obtenerlo. Para el tema de calendario suelo usar Calendar de esta forma. Es un ejemplo:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
        dia = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mes = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        anio = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar este método, en base a obtener el día máximo del mes mediante `getActualMaximum()`, se define el día que deseamos `Calendar.MONDAY` y obtenemos el día en base a una resta del día máximo :

```
    final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
    //cal = getLastMonday(cal, 0 /* this month */);
    int dayofweek;
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 0 /* 0 this month, 1 next month and so on..,. */);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    dayofweek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if (dayofweek < Calendar.MONDAY) {
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 7 + Calendar.MONDAY - dayofweek);
    }else {
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + Calendar.MONDAY - dayofweek);
    }
    String lastMondayofMonth = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

en base a lo anterior puedes usar este método el cual recibe el mes (Enero es 1 y así sucesivamente) y el año del cual deseas obtener el último lunes del mes.

```
private static String getLastMondayofMonth(int month, int year){
    final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);

    int dayofweek;
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1 /* January 0 and so on..*/);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    dayofweek =cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if (dayofweek < Calendar.MONDAY) {
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 7 + Calendar.MONDAY - dayofweek);
    }else {
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + Calendar.MONDAY - dayofweek);
    }
    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

[**Ejemplo utilizando el método anterior.**](https://www.ideone.com/Gh3Tcz)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad `DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH` creo que este método es el más sencillo.

```
public Date ObtenerUltimoLunes( int mes, int anio ) 
{
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
    calendar.set( anio, mes, 1 );
    calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.MONDAY);
    calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, -1);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```